# ignore case in xs:unique?

Tags: xml

Is it possible to use `xs:unique` to ignore case, that is, flag as duplicate two values that differ only in capitalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not, take a look at the MSDN where the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256146.aspx) states:

> ### xsd:unique Element
>
> Specifies that an attribute or element value (or a combination of
>   attribute or element values) must be unique within the specified
>   scope. The value must be unique or nil.

On [another Microsoft site(Performance Counters Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it states *indirectly* that the value within the following code part **has to be case-sensitive**:

```
<xs:unique name="uniqueCounterName">
   <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
         Counter Name must be unique within the Counter Set. The name is
         case-sensitive.
       </xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>
   <xs:selector xpath="./man:counter"/>
   <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
</xs:unique>
```